# Doing search queries on many to many relationships

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Can I share my headches with you? I'm trying to do a search with this piece of code. (Line with arrow)

```
def index
    search = params[:user][:subject_ids]
---->   @users = User.includes(:subjects).where(role: 'instructor')
    @user = current_user
end
```

It's a many to many association. I have users, enrollements and subjects. I have instructors who have signed up to teach 1-5 courses. When I do the search, I get list of all the instructors, not just the ones teaching the subject I queried for.

Not sure where to go from here.

Associations

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :enrollments, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :subjects, through: :enrollments
end
```

---

```
class Subject < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :enrollments, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :users, through: :enrollments

end
```

---

```
class Enrollment < ActiveRecord::Base 

  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :subject

end
```

Thank you for your time.

Comment: is there a single subject id in `params[:user][:subject_ids]` ?

Comment: Yes. It pulls it from the predefined dropdown menu.

Comment: Is it correct to assume that users with the role 'instructor' are all related to subjects through enrolments in the database?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot to put the search parameter in your query.
Your line should look something like this:

```
@users = User.includes([:enrolments,:subjects]).where("user.role" => 'instructor', "subjects.id" => search)
```

Comment: It didn't work :( but thanks to you I'm getting closer. I can feel it. Thanks Toby.

Comment: I edited the code above, to make things a little more explicit. Try it again.

Comment: It sent me Rails infamous page with this error PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column subjects.subject_id does not exist
LINE 1: ...ments"."subject_id" WHERE "users"."role" = $1 AND "subjects"...

Comment: whoops, my mistake: just change "subjects.subject_id" to "subjects.id". I'll change it in my answer

Comment: Oh my goodness! IT WORKS! I thought I was going to go insane. Thanks a lot Toby. You're the man. (Cool username)